# How to avoid specifying a class name multiple times in html?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a table where each cell more or less looks the same and controlled by CSS classes.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="xx">
      blah blah
    </td>
    <td class="xx">
      blah blah
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="xx">
      blah blah
    </td>
    <td class="xx">
      blah blah
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to avoid specifying `class="xx"` for every `<td>`?  The classes are not defined by me, but from a CSS framework and there are multiple classes to specify on each element. This means that **changing the CSS definition is not an option**

**EDIT**
I should have mentioned that I am using W3.CSS and wanted to refer classes from it.  I did some research on this and came to the same conclusion as the accepted answer (that what I am asking is not possible with HTML).  But I thought someone may show some way of doing it without having to re-define the class from W3.CSS, so I asked here.

Comment: You can define td in CSS, and then define one or more classes for those td elements that should be different.

Comment: You can use tag as css selector instead of class.

Comment: can give example? Can't understand the downvotes.  I am trying to save space here by specifying class name once.  There are a list of class names ( more than 3).

Comment: you are using `xx` and everyone is understanding that they are all the same and not different classes

Comment: They are not different class.. All <td> should look the same and I am spefiying class names defined in W3.CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp.  Just want to know whether I can just specify once instead of several times.

Comment: No...you cant. If you want two different elements to have the same styling then they need the same class or selector. As has been specificied you can apply a class to a parent and select all appropriate children but that's quite fragile.

Comment: Frankly, W3Schools is awful, CSS frameworks are more trouble then they are worth, and you'd be better throwing W3.CSS out and writing your own stylesheet.

Comment: @Quentin.. They make a good start.. I guess what I ask for is not possible.. so just thinking of copying what is defined by w3.css as my own class..

Comment: "They make a good start" — No, they make a terrible *start*. They provide a quick way to build something within their own constraints and with bloated HTML — so they are fine if that is where you want to get to and stop. To get something efficient or particularly custom, you have to chuck them out.

Comment: @Quentin Agreed.. If I am happy with what they provide, then use them, else define custom - this is what I am trying to say..

Comment: If you can't change the CSS then you have to put the styling in the HTML (somehow - either by literal insertion or by scripting something that will alter the styles after the script is loaded; this is tending towards a dirty unmaintainable hack). The end.

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387079/high-downvotes-for-a-question-with-purpose)

Comment: @Script47 I guess it is not correct to tag the meta post here. It is not relevant to the subject being discussed here. As it is, it is attracting a lot of downvotes, which I think isn't fair.

Comment: @arunsiara.cc _you_ made a post on meta linking to main, I linked from main to meta, the down-votes are coming from your post, not a result of my linking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, this will reduce your class and will give you specific class to target.

```css
.xx td{color:#ff0000}
```

```html
<table class="xx">
  <tr>
    <td>
      blah blah
    </td>
    <td>
      blah blah
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      blah blah
    </td>
    <td>
      blah blah
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: none of the answers help me.. I already have class names from W3.CSS.. I just want to re-use them and specify them once instead of for every td.. not define again using css styles..

Comment: to target any element you must required a selector in terms of css class or you can use direct html tag as per my example, this is the only way to reduce your css class name.

Comment: did you got the answer or still have any doubt?

Comment: Yes i saw that - That bcoz it's all about css selector may be that was the reason - don't worry you will get it back soon.

Comment: Saving space and reducing clutter isn't always a good thing. If you go to ridiculous lengths to save a few bytes the. You make your code harder to maintain and understand. Bandwidth is cheap; if you're going to impose restrictions like "I can't change the CSS" when the CSS is designed to be the thing that is changed, then you'll have to burn some more bytes

Answer (score 1):

You can do,

```
td {
  //Your code here
}
```

Put your code inside the `td` tag so you do not have to put `xx` class in every `td` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can give class to table using jQuery and use that class to give css to td.

```
.abc td {....}
```

It's good practice to avoid multiple time define class in HTML.

It will work.